# Discovering Gimbal iBeacons

Tags: ios, ibeacon, gimbal

Using https://github.com/welbesw/iBeaconExamples I created an app that monitors for a specific UUID, as given in the source. It works perfectly when I use two iPhones, one as broadcaster and one as monitor.

When I however change the UUID to the one I set up my Gimbal iBeacon with (using [Gimbal beacon discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310220/gimbal-beacon-discovery)), it cannot find the beacon. Also when I register the UUID (which I specified in the "manage configurations" bit in the Gimbal Manager) in other apps such as BLExplr or Locate IB (Radius Networks) it can't be found. BLExplr does find the beacon's Bluetooth Service UUID ([iOS iBeacon: How to get all of proximityUUID programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163290/ios-ibeacon-how-to-get-all-of-proximityuuid-programmatically)), so it's definitely broadcasting...

Does anyone have an idea what could be the solution here?

Comment: Are you sure your Gimbal beacon is operating in iBeacon mode, and not in Gimbal proprietary mode?  Are you absolutely sure you transcribed the UUID correctly?  If you have access to a BLE enabled Android device or a USB BLE dongle you have more options for figuring out what it is actually transmitting than you do with the locked-down iOS device, which gives you next to no visibility unless there's an exact UUID match with a proper iBeacon packet.

Comment: Pretty much, but I'll double check! Maybe I can find a friend's Android to get more info! Thanks!!